# Are imperfectly constructed sentences understandable?

Tags: american-english, british-english, interpretation, learning

As an English learner, when building a sentence in my head it is almost impossible to get it out idiomatically. For example, before I knew the word "regarding" I built this sentence:

> "This bus will get you where you want to go, otherwise of what your friend is saying."

I meant to say:

> "This bus will get you where you want to go, regardless what your friend is saying."

I used the first sentence in talking with a native English speaker and she understood me. But I was ashamed to ask if she understood it right a way or if it took her some time.

I'm curious to know if a native English speaker would quickly and easily understand "This bus will get you where you want to go, otherwise of what your friend is saying" immediately, or only after working hard to understand the intended meaning of the sentence for a length of time?

Comment: It's entirely a matter of exact context whether your use of ***otherwise*** would be understood there. I can easily imagine thinking you meant *I am **another person** saying the same thing as your friend*. But you could presumably express yourself with no risk of ambiguity or uncertainty simply by using far more words. There's no point in striving for the shortest possible way of saying something if you don't actually *know* how native Anglophones would say it - you're never going to pass for a native Anglophone yourself, so just use more words in simpler constructions to ensure clarity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that is interesting, can you please elaborate more on how you came to understand "another person saying the same thing as your friend" I think it would help me with my english reasoning

Comment: No, I don't think analysis of my reaction would help you here. All I mean is "otherwise" is not a useful word for your context, and you shouldn't assume people will be able to guess your intended meaning just because that word implies some kind of "difference". Just use short simple phrasing, such as *Your friend is wrong! This bus goes to XXXX* (I assume you know what XXXX is at the time, so why complicate things with *...will get you where you want to go*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I understand your point of view, still I belive it would enhance the way I think to buil sentences. I always appreciate differents insights

Comment: Native speakers of *any* language (including yours, I'm sure) learn by hearing and ***using*** simple constructions. It's completely unnatural to attempt to learn and use complex forms before you've acquired near-total fluency using simple forms that are more than capable of expressing *any* thought you could possibly have. We never need complex syntax or exotic vocabulary to get our message across flawlessly and in my experience less competent *thinkers* often use obscure verbiage to "conceal" the fact that they don't really understand their subject matter. (KISS is a valuable principle! :)

Comment: The term is colloquial speech,  not talking. Question title: Understanding colloquial speech. What is a mind-built sentence?? otherwise and regardless are not synonyms. The word English takes a capital e. Are you trying to say **apesar de** in English? To build a sentence in their head, not in head.

Answer (score 1):

The right phrase is "regardless **of** what your friend is saying", not just "regardless", and please note that it's not the same as the word "regarding".

Since "otherwise of" is not a phrase I recognize in American English, I might be able to understand that you had meant to say "regardless of" instead of "otherwise of". However, it might also take some time to understand because the normal use of "otherwise" in that position would be to mean "if not":

> This bus will get you where you want to go, **otherwise,** you can call a taxi.

It's more important to express your ideas and keep a conversation going than to use perfect grammar and idioms, so you did the right thing. But next time, as you know, you should use "regardless of".

Comment: *Regardless* without the *of* sounds fine to me, a native speaker of American English.

Answer (score 1):

My direct answer is that no, I didn't easily understand what you meant. I had to stop and think about it, and without your explanation I might have constructed an alternative meaning.

But to encourage you, I would say: don't worry about it. I've had experience over the years with multicultural church contexts, and the level of English with non native speakers has ranged from zero to fluent! In that setting we get by, with grace and patience on all sides. I agree with @fFumbleFingers about the importance of simplicity. I find that the best way forward is for the native English speakers to slow down their speech, to listen carefully, and to say things in very simplified forms. I imagine that's equally true for other languages.

For example, consider "*This bus will get you where you want to go, otherwise of what your friend is saying*." There are many variations:

- This bus will get you to X.
- This bus is going to X.
- This is the bus you should catch.
- You should get on this bus. (Your friend is wrong!)

That's my advice if you simply want to **communicate clearly**. If you want to **improve** your English, my advice would be different. Try asking people if you have said something correctly. If you said the OP sentence to me and then asked if your English was correct, I would have been glad to help you out.